# What is the difference between the solid fuel Boosters of the Shuttle and Artemis?

Tags: space-shuttle, solid-fuel, booster, artemis-program

The Shuttle boosters had 4 segments and Artemis has 5. What are the differences in total mass, thrust and burn time? Is the thrust profile (thrust over time) the same?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(This answer assumes the the SLS SRBs are the same as the Five-Segment Boosters (FSBs) studied for a shuttle upgrade...I believe they are, but have not seen this explicitly stated).

The thrust time curves are compared here

[image]

- RSRM = Redesigned Solid Rocket Motor (shuttle SRB)
- FSB1 = Five Segment Booster (not sure about the 1)

Reference (a paper by my old boss):

[Achieving Space Shuttle
Abort-to-Orbit Using the
Five-Segment Booster](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20030066231/downloads/20030066231.pdf)

Weight difference:

- Shuttle SRB: 1,300,000 lb ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster))
- SLS SRB: 1,600,000 lb ([NASA SLS SRB fact sheet](https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/fs/solid-rocket-booster.html))

Other differences:

[image]

Ignore the part about parachutes. No chutes on SLS boosters.

Source:

[Achieving Space Shuttle ATO Using the Five-Segment Booster (FSB)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20030066231/downloads/20030066231.pdf)

Addendum:

Thanks to [Jörg W Mittag](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/6156/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) who suggested in a comment that the SLS SRBs might have been derived from the Ares 1 design. I found a plot for that, which looks superficially similar to the one above except for maybe a bigger thrust difference on the "second hump". Also it's a clearer image.

[image]

Source [Ares First Stage Element Status](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20090037677/downloads/20090037677.pdf)

Comment: Great comparison, but that NASA fact sheet for the SLS SRB gives 3.6 million pounds and 126 sec. burntime.  Not that much of a difference  though ! :)

Comment: @Cornelis thanks! I'll try and find a newer thrust-time curve.

Comment: I heard that the SLS FSBs are actually (based on) the Ares I first stage ones. Could that account for the thrust profile difference?

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks! A curve for Ares might be available.